# How to display classification report in flask web application

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, plotly-dash, data-science-experience

i need output to be displayed in classification matrix from 
but i am getting a string as output

```
from pyod.models.xgbod import XGBClassifier
clf = XGBClassifier(max_depth=15, min_child_weight=4, gamma=0.3,
                    colsample_bytree=0.4)  # max_depth = 15, min_child_weight =4
clf.fit(x_train[:, np.newaxis], y_train)

y_pred1 = clf.predict(x_test[:, np.newaxis])
y_prob1 = clf.predict_proba(x_test[:, np.newaxis])

n_errors1 = (y_pred1 != y_test).sum()
print('')
print('XG boost no of Errors :{}'.format(n_errors1))
print('Accuracy Score: ', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1))
print('Classification report :')
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred1))
av = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1)
cv = classification_report(y_test, y_pred1)

f1_score_xgb =   f1_score(y_test, y_pred1, average='weighted')
print(f1_score_xgb)

return render_template('classification_report.html',cv = cv,f1_score =f1_score_xgb)
```

output :

XGBOOST::
classification report and accuracy score : precision recall f1-score support 0 0.92 1.00 0.96 4073 1 0.90 0.23 0.36 466 micro avg 0.92 0.92 0.92 4539 macro avg 0.91 0.61 0.66 4539 weighted avg 0.92 0.92 0.89 4539

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XG_BOOST Accuracy & C_report</title></head>
<body><h1> XGBOOST::</h1>
<p> classification report and accuracy score :{{cv}} </p>
<p> f1 score {{f1_score}}</p>
<p>print(cv)</p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also include `classification_report.html`?

Comment: including html report thanks

Comment: classificationreport.html:
'''

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XG_BOOST Accuracy & C_report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> XGBOOST::</h1>
    <p> classification report and accuracy score :{{cv}} </p>
    <p> f1 score  {{f1_score}}</p>



  <p>print(cv)</p>
</body>
</html>'''

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your HTML. It should display a title with three paragraphs under it. What do you see?.

Comment: i just see  classification report displayed as string                                                                       XGBOOST:: classification report and accuracy score : precision recall f1-score support 0 0.92 1.00 0.96 4073 1 0.90 0.23 0.36 466 micro avg 0.92 0.92 0.92 4539 macro avg 0.91 0.61 0.66 4539 weighted avg 0.92 0.92 0.89 4539

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to set this classification matrix template in html first. I would suggest you to read this blog. [simple-tables-in-webapps-using-flask-and-pandas-with-python](https://sarahleejane.github.io/learning/python/2015/08/09/simple-tables-in-webapps-using-flask-and-pandas-with-python.html)